# Perl Hash of Arrays using Column Data as Keys

Tags: mysql, arrays, perl, hash

My SQL database has three columns; `Key`, `Topic`, and `Value`.  There are duplicate topics that have different values.  Here is a sample:

```
 Key    Topic  Value
 -----  -----  -----
 1      Book      20
 2      Toy       10
 3      Toy       30
 4      Pet      100
 5      Book      15
 .      .          .
 .      .          .
```

Using Perl, how do I create a hash from the column `Topic` (`%Topic`) that uses each unique key in `Topic` as an array that has the corresponding values for its elements: `@Book = 20, 15, ...`, `@Toy = 10, 30, ...`, `@Pet = 100, ...`.

Comment: The two version of the table you've been posting hasn't been readable. Fixed.

Comment: But your question itself needs fixing. A unique key cannot be an array, for starters. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a hash keyed by Topic, where the value is a reference to an array with the Values for that Topic.

```
my %values_by_topic;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT Topic, Value FROM Table');
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetch()) {
   my ($topic, $value) = @$row;
    push @{ $values_by_topic{$topic} }, $value;
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up question.  How do you perform entropy calculations on the values of each topic?  I would like to rank the topic based on its entropy value.

Comment: I have no idea what that means. Best start a new question.

Comment: Ok. I will submit a new question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql side:

```
select Topic, group_concat(Value) as Value
from t
group by Topic
```